# Run a Spring Boot application with elastic-apm Java agent on OpenShift

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, javaagents, apm, elastic-apm

I want to deploy a Spring Boot application on an OpenShift cluster that I want to monitor with *elastic-apm*, therefore, with the [JAVA elastic agent](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/current/index.html).

I managed to deploy in a project an Elasticsearch instance, a [Kibana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibana) instance and an apm-server.

Next to that, I also managed to deploy my Spring Boot application. For this I used the web console. I imported my project from [GitLab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitLab), and chose the Java 8 image builder. However, using this method, I didn't find a way to launch my application by associating the java-agent elastic-apm-agent.

Locally, I run this command to start my application:

```
mvn package && java -javaagent:elastic-apm-agent/elastic-apm-agent-1.26.0.jar \
-Delastic.apm.service_name=ms-salarie \
-Delastic.apm.server_urls=http://localhost:8200 \
-Delastic.apm.secret_token= \
-Delastic.apm.environment=development \
-Delastic.apm.application_packages=com.leanerp.salarie \
-Delastic.apm.config_file=elastic-apm-agent/elasticapm.properties \
-jar target/salarie-1.1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Is there a way to override the command launched by the container of my application? Or another solution allowing me to use the elastic-apm-agent?

<sub>I am a newbie on OpenShift, so I don't fully understand all the concepts.</sub>

Comment: What is "elastic-apm"? Can you provide a reference to it? Please respond by [editing (changing) your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69828374/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the answer was adding this environment variable :

```
JAVA_OPTS_APPEND=-javaagent:{{path_to_elastic_apm_agent}}
```

this command allows you to launch your java application with options.

Answer (score 1):

The Java agent allows multiple ways to configure it, one of which are command line system properties. Others include packaging an `elasticapm.properties` resource file or setting environment variables.

[Check out the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/current/configuration.html). Small excerpt:

> - **Properties file**: The `elasticapm.properties` file is located in the same folder as the agent jar, or provided through the `config_file` option. dynamic config.
> - **Environment variables**: All configuration keys are in uppercase and prefixed with `ELASTIC_APM_`.

Different option sources have different priority and precedence.

To attach the agent to a running JVM process (from within your application), you can use the [API to self-attach](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/master/setup-attach-api.html#setup-attach-api-configuration).

Comment: Perhaps I misspoke.
Locally, I can link the agent to my application and view the metrics on kibana.

However, my problem is more related to the launching of this agent on openshift. Looking at the documentation, I have the impression that this one is more about the agent configuration, which is not really my problem.

My problem is more about the java 8 image builder in openshift.

Comment: Oh right, because you need to set the agent during startup. I missed that, sorry. Do you know about the [agent API to self-attach](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/java/master/setup-attach-api.html)?